# How to Subtract the Max Value and Min Value from the Sum in an Array

Tags: javascript, html

My code has no problem adding up the values in the `sum`. The issue is subracting `min` value and `max` value from the overall `sum` that gets outputted in the empty div `results`. When the program is ran, it still adds up all values that were inputted. I have attempted it a few times and this is where I stopped.

```
<script>

            
        function computeScore(){
            let scores = [
                judgeA = document.getElementById("judgeA").value,
                judgeB = document.getElementById("judgeB").value,
                judgeC = document.getElementById("judgeC").value,
                judgeD = document.getElementById("judgeD").value,
                judgeE = document.getElementById("judgeE").value,
                judgeF = document.getElementById("judgeF").value,
                judgeG = document.getElementById("judgeG").value,
                judgeH = document.getElementById("judgeH").value
            ];
            let min= Math.min(...scores);
            let max= Math.min(...scores);
            let sum=0;
            let avg=0;
            
            function calculateSum() {
             for(let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
                sum += Number(scores[i]);

                console.log((sum-max)-min);
            }
             calculateSum();

             document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = sum;
            
        }

    </script>
</head>
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Olympic Judging Calculator </h1>
  
    <form id=myForm>
  
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Country A Judge:</td>
          <td><input id="judgeA" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country B Judge:</td>
          <td> <input id="judgeB" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country C Judge:</td>
          <td><input id="judgeC" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country D Judge:</td>
          <td> <input id="judgeD" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country E Judge:</td>
          <td> <input id="judgeE" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country F Judge:</td>
          <td> <input id="judgeF" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country G Judge:</td>
          <td> <input id="judgeG" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country H Judge:</td>
          <td> <input id="judgeH" type="number" value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <input type="button" value="Compute Score" onclick="computeScore()">

  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at `let max= Math.min(...scores);` line,

It should have been `let max= Math.max(...scores);`.

Since you are calculating wrong max value, your sum value is wrong.

Also, I think you forgot to subtract the min and max values from sum while setting it to the **result**.